# Google Sheets, returning a text value based on relative rank

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a relative ranking structure based on cell values within a repeating range.

I have ranked the text values accordingly.
[Text Ranks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQdzz.png)

I then have a sheet with columns that contain subsets of these text values like so;
[Text Value Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5A1x.png)

What I am trying to accomplish, is that when a Rank of 1 is entered into a cell in row A, it will return the highest value of that row based on the column values in row B. So as an example;

If 1 was entered into cell A2, it would return "Text 1" in B2. If 2 was entered in A2 it would return "Text 3" in B2. If 3 was entered in A2 it would return "text 5". If any other rank (4-20) was entered B2 would remain blank. The same would happen in Row 3 except it would consider "Text 2" as rank 1, "Text 3" as rank 2, and "Text 4" as rank 3.

I can make this work in Excel with XLOOKUP but I've been unable to solve the problem with Google Sheets, any help here would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

#### Formula (B7):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(SORT(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(C7:7), {Sheet2!$B$2:$B$21,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$21}, 2, FALSE)), Sheet2!$A$2:$B$21, 2, FALSE)), A7), "")`

#### Sheet2:

[image: sheet2]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Formula steps:

1. `TRANSPOSE` the row into column to be able to use `VLOOKUP` and compare it to the `Sheet2` Table.
2. Use `VLOOKUP` to return the rank.
3. `SORT` the rank.
4. `VLOOKUP` again to look the values in the `Sheet2` and now return the text values
5. At this point, we now have the list of sorted text values based on our row values, now we use the given rank and get the sorted text value based on rank using `INDEX`
6. If it returns `#N/A`, return blank instead.

#### Step by step visualization of the formula for the 7th row:

[image: visualization]

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked like a charm!

Comment: hi @Mike4President, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK copying down the formula, then this should work:

`=iferror(index(split(textjoin(char(6655),true,$C2:$G2),char(6655)),$A2),"")`

The values on the row are joined together using `TEXTJOIN`, separated by `CHAR(6655)` which is a character you wouldn't expect to have in your text. The `true` in the `TEXTJOIN` removes blank cells. Then `SPLIT` breaks the text into separate cells using `CHAR(6655)`.

`INDEX` then gets the corresponding cell value dependent on your Rank value in column A.

`IFERROR` displays nothing (`""`) if the Rank value is greater than the number of cells of data.

[image]